# Seemingly random opendir() failure C

Tags: c, opendir

So I've written a short C program that explores the files on my computer to look for a certain file. I wrote a simple function that takes a directory, opens it an looks around:

```
int exploreDIR (char stringDIR[], char search[])
{    
    DIR* dir;
    struct dirent* ent;   

    if ((dir = opendir(stringDIR)) == NULL)
    {
         printf("Error: could not open directory %s\n", stringDIR);
         return 0;             
    }

    while ((ent = readdir(dir)) != NULL)
    {
        if(strcmp(ent->d_name, ".") == 0 || strcmp(ent->d_name, "..") == 0)
             continue;

        if (strlen(stringDIR) + 1 + strlen(ent->d_name) > 1024)
        {
            perror("\nError: File path is too long!\n");
            continue;
        }     

        char filePath[1024];
        strcpy(filePath, stringDIR);
        strcat(filePath, "/");
        strcat(filePath, ent->d_name);

        if (strcmp(ent->d_name, search) == 0)
        {
            printf(" Found it! It's at: %s\n", filePath);
            return 1;
        }

        struct stat st; 
        if (lstat(filePath, &st) < 0)
        {
            perror("Error: lstat() failure");
            continue; 
        }

        if (st.st_mode & S_IFDIR)
        {
             DIR* tempdir;
             if ((tempdir = opendir (filePath)))
             {
                 exploreDIR(filePath, search);               
             }

         }

    }
    closedir(dir);
    return 0; 
}
```

However, I keep getting the output:

```
Error: could not open directory /Users/Dan/Desktop/Box/Videos
Error: could not open directory /Users/Dan/Desktop/compilerHome
```

The problem is, I have no idea what it is about these files that could cause opendir() to fail. I don't have them open in any program. They're just simple folders I created on my desktop. Does anyone have any idea what the problem could be?

Comment: `chmod r+x /Users/Dan/Desktop/Box/Videos` and retry.

Comment: just execute via `sudo`

Comment: What does examining `errno` tell you?

Comment: You are calling opendir() twice for each closedir(). Maybe you are running out of resources.

Comment: @ZagorulkinDmitry: Bad idea. Don't use `sudo`, or root access in general, for anything for which it's not necessary. And in this case it wouldn't help anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling `opendir()` twice for each `closedir()`. Maybe you are running out of resources.

Comment: Ah, that was the problem! I can't believe I forgot about the second opendir(). Thank you.